# Code on window closing in App Delegate?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a Mac application where I would like to save some values when the window closes. However, I can't figure out how to do this. I have the application delegate controlling the main window (which may not be the way you are supposed to do it, and I probably shouldn't have done it this way if what I've read previously is correct) and I can't figure out for the life of me how to do this! I believe it can be done using a NSWindowController, but can you do it in the app delegate? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **NSWindowWillCloseNotification**.

```
- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowWillClose:) name:NSWindowWillCloseNotification object:window];
}

- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Your code for saving data
}
```

Comment: Now, this might be a stupid question, but can I just copy and paste that? Will it work right off the bat...?